# Every 4-dimensional isotropic quadratic space of determinant 1 is hyperbolic

Tags: quadratic-forms

There is this claim in Scharlau's "Quadratic and Hermitian forms",

> Every 4-dimensional isotropic quadratic space of determinant 1 is hyperbolic.

How can we prove it? I know that any 2-dimensional isotropic quadratic space is hyperbolic, I understand the proof but I don't see how I could extend the result to four dimensions.

Comment: The thing is, the same proof that any 2-dimensional isotropic quadratic space is hyperbolic proves that any isotropic quadratic space contains an hyperbolic plane! That's the essential piece I was missing out on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, after some help from my teacher. It's not hard, I was just missing on a couple of elementary results that are useful.

Let $(V,q)$ be such an $F$-quadratic space. As it is isotropic, then $V$ contains a hyperbolic plane, and as hyperbolic planes are non-degenerate, it admits an orthogonal complement. So, $$q\simeq \langle 1,-1,e,f\rangle$$ for some $e,f\in F^*$.

Comparing (square classes of) determinants, we get that $-ef=\alpha^2$ for some $\alpha\in F^*$. Dividing the last component of the diagonalization of $q$ as above by $\alpha^2$ and then multiplying it by $e^2$, we get $$q\simeq \langle 1,-1,e,-e \rangle  \simeq 2\mathbb H$$ as $\langle \omega,-\omega\rangle \simeq \mathbb H$ for any $\omega\in F^*$. Thus the assertion is proved.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889748/about-3-dimensional-quadratic-space