# About 3-dimensional quadratic space

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, semigroups, invariant-theory

> **3.3 Theorem.**
>   Assume that every $3$-dimensional quadratic space over $K$ is isotropic.
>   Let $\phi$ be a regular $n$-dimensional quadratic space.
>   Then
>   $$
>         \phi
>   \cong \langle \delta, 1, \dotsc, 1 \rangle
>   \qquad
>   \text{where $\delta = \det(\phi)$}.
> $$
>   In  particular, two regular quadratic spaces are isometric if and only if they have equal dimension and determinant.
>   Moreover,
>   $$
>         \hat{W}(K)
>   \cong \mathbb{Z} \times K^\bullet / K^{\bullet 2}
>   \quad\text{and}\quad
>         W(K)
>   \cong Q(K).
> $$
>
> *Proof:*
>   Since $\langle \alpha, \beta, -1 \rangle$ is isotropic this space splits off a hyperbolic plane and thus $\langle \alpha, \beta, -1 \rangle \cong \langle \gamma, 1, -1 \rangle$.
>   By the cancellation law $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \gamma, 1 \rangle$.
>   Comparing determinants we see that for any $2$-dimensional form $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \alpha \beta, 1 \rangle$.
>   Using this and proceeding inductively we get
>   $$
>         \langle \alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n \rangle
>   \cong \langle \alpha_1 \dotso \alpha_n, 1, \dotsc, 1 \rangle.
> $$
>   This proves the first assertion.
>   The second is an immediate consequence.
>   We leave it to the reader to verify that
>   \begin{align*}
>           (\dim, \det)
>   &\colon \hat{W}(K)
>    \to    \mathbb{Z} \times K^\bullet / K^{\bullet 2}
> \\
>           (e,d)
>   &\colon W(K)
>    \to    Q(K)
> \end{align*}
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndjjx.png).)

This is excerpt from W. Scharlau: *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms,*
[page 38](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA38).

For defination of $e, d$ and other maps use 
[page 35](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35).

First of all I don't understand why they use specific three dimensional space as $\langle \alpha, \beta , -1  \rangle$ .
Now since we know the above space is isotropic we can split it into hyperbolic plane. Also after that by cancellation law we get $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \gamma, 1\rangle$. After that how do we know from looking at the determinant that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \alpha \beta, 1 \rangle$? After that how do we get isomorphisms by the maps $(\dim,\det)$ and $(e,d)$?

Comment: This is an old post, but I had the same question today, so for anyone else looking, here's what I garner. From knowing $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \gamma ,1 \rangle$, it follows that $\det \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \det \langle \gamma,1 \rangle \pmod{{K^\bullet} ^2}$, so $\alpha \beta a^2 = \gamma$ for some $a \in K^{\bullet}$. Then $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong \langle \alpha \beta a^2 ,1 \rangle \cong \langle \alpha \beta , 1 \rangle$.